# Банальный вопрос по функциям в js

Tags: javascript

```js
function myFirstApp(name, age) {
  alert(`Привет, меня зовут ${name} и это моя первая программа`);

  function showSkills() {
    let skills = ['html', 'css', 'js'];
    for (let i = 0; i < skills.length; i++) {
      document.write(`Я владею ${skills[i]}`);
    }
  }

  function checkAge() {
    if (age > 18) {
      alert("У тебя отличные шансы!!!");
    } else {
      alert("Тоби !!!!!!!!");
    }
  }

  function calcPow(num) {
    console.log(Math.pow(num, num));
  }
}

myFirstApp("Garry", 48);
```

Начинаю только учить js. Непонятно, почему здесь вызвались только первая alert() остальные вложенные функции при этом не были выполнены?

Comment: Потому что они только объявлены, но не вызваны.

Comment: Точно, только покурить успел и понял, что не вызывал их в скрипте))) Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

При работе с функциями и методами в любом языке программирования следует различать их объявление и вызов:

```
function showSkills() {
    let skills = ['html', 'css', 'js'];
    for (let i = 0; i < skills.length; i++) {
        document.write(`Я владею ${skills[i]}`);
    }
}
```

Здесь вы объявили функцию `showSkills()`, описали, какие параметры она принимает и что делает. Теперь, чтобы исполнить код функции в определённом участке вашего скрипта, её нужно вызвать:

```
showSkills();
```

Второй момент - избыточность вашего кода: функции нужны тогда, когда вы планируете выполнить одно и то же действие несколько раз или с разными параметрами. Однако если задача функции `MyFirstApp` в том, чтобы просто поочерёдно выполнить вложенные в неё функции, как вы, видимо, и ожидали, то функции там и не нужны. Этот код:

```js
function myFirstApp(name, age) {
    alert(`Привет, меня зовут ${name} и это моя первая программа`);
    let skills = ['html', 'css', 'js'];
    for (let i = 0; i < skills.length; i++) {
        document.write(`Я владею ${skills[i]}`);
    }
    if (age > 18) {
        alert("У тебя отличные шансы!!!");
    } else {
        alert("Тоби всё!!!!!!!!");
    }
    console.log(Math.pow(4, 4));
}
myFirstApp("Garry", 48);
```

Сделает то же самое, но займёт меньше места.

Также хочу отметить, что функции вовсе необязательно вкладывать друг в друга: в область видимости вашей функции входит как её код, так и код скрипта, в котором она расположена, но не код других функций. То есть, можно сделать вот так:

```js
function myFirstApp(name, age) {
    alert(`Привет, меня зовут ${name} и это моя первая программа`);
    showSkills();
    if (age > 18) {
        alert("У тебя отличные шансы!!!");
    } else {
        alert("Тоби всё!!!!!!!!");
    }
    console.log(Math.pow(4, 4));
}
function showSkills() {
    let skills = ['html', 'css', 'js'];
    for (let i = 0; i < skills.length; i++) {
        document.write(`Я владею ${skills[i]}`);
    }
}
myFirstApp("Garry", 48);
```

Но не так:

```js
function myFirstApp(name, age) {
    alert(`Привет, меня зовут ${name} и это моя первая программа`);
    showSkills();
    console.log(skills[0]); //Ошибка: ReferenceError: skills is not defined
    if (age > 18) {
        alert("У тебя отличные шансы!!!");
    } else {
        alert("Тоби всё!!!!!!!!");
    }
    console.log(Math.pow(4, 4));
}
function showSkills() {
    let skills = ['html', 'css', 'js'];
    for (let i = 0; i < skills.length; i++) {
        document.write(`Я владею ${skills[i]}`);
    }
}
myFirstApp("Garry", 48);
```

Это происходит потому, что переменные функций и методов существуют только в момент их исполнения, а значит не могут быть вызваны извне, вызвать можно только саму функцию.

Отсюда следует и ещё один важный момент: вкладывая одну функцию внутри другой вы делаете её недоступной извне родительской функции, так как все функции, объявленные в другой функции будут объявлены только после вызова вышестоящей функции и удалены из памяти по её завершению. Таким образом, вкладывать одну функцию в другую имеет смысл тогда, когда эта функция не будет вызвана нигде в коде, кроме как внутри родительской функции.

Однако чаще всего, когда вам надо объявлять вложенные функции - лучше объявить [класс](https://learn.javascript.ru/class) с методами. А вот методы класса уже могут быть доступны извне, через экземпляр класса.

Comment: "функции нужны тогда, когда вы планируете выполнить одно и то же действие несколько раз" - нет, "переменные функций и методов существуют только в момент их исполнения" - нет

Comment: @Igor по вашим словам выходит, что функция вообще бесполезная штука.) И память они не разгружают, и код не оптимизируют, прямо беда. Любое обучение программированию начинается с объяснения, что типовые действия надо выносить в функции. Про переменные, впрочем, готов посмотреть на пруфы, может я чего и не знаю. Вот только в инспекторе переменная неиспользуемой функции будет не определена.

Answer (score -4):

```js
function myFirstApp(name, age) {
    alert(`Привет, меня зовут ${name} и это моя первая программа`);

    function showSkills() {
        let skills = ['html', 'css', 'js'];
        for (let i = 0; i < skills.length; i++) {
            document.write(`Я владею ${skills[i]}`);
        }
    }

    function checkAge() {
        if (age > 18) {
            alert("У тебя отличные шансы!!!");
        } else {
            alert("Тоби всё!!!!!!!!");
        }
    }

    function calcPow(num) {
        console.log(Math.pow(num, num));
    }
    showSkills();
    checkAge();
    calcPow(4);
}
```

Для таких же темных как и я, на будущее)

Comment: Если отвечаете на свой вопрос, то, пожалуйста, понятно и развёрнуто опишите в чём ошибка, чтобы ответ представлял ценность для всего сообщества. Новичок в программировании может не понимать, как работают функции, и тогда ваш код, применимый только к вашему примеру, ничем ему не поможет.